# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties. ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I try to make REST API by tutorial in youtube but i have the next error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
> properties:
> 'Application.Dependency.AddApplication(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'
> and
> 'Application.Dependency.AddApplication(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'

I understand that I have 2 identical methods and it does not understand which one to choose, but I cannot understand why this error occurs and how to fix it.

File Application.Dependency.cs:

```
using Application.Services.Authentication; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    
    
namespace Application; 
public static class Dependency {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
    
            return services;
        } 
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using Infrastructure;
using Application;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
{
    builder.Services.AddApplication().AddInfrastructure();
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
}
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[Code repository](https://github.com/SilverMoon17/BuberDinner)

Comment: "but I cannot understand why this error occurs and how to fix it" - it presumably occurs *because* you have two identical methods, and to fix it you should get rid of one of them. What part of the tutorial suggested you should have two identical methods?

Comment: Hmm, l think I have seen a similar (if not the same) error caused by multiple versions of the same nuget package being referenced. Check each project and what packages and versions are being referenced

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, but i cannot find where is the 2 method

Comment: Ah, so when you say "I understand that I have 2 identical methods" you mean you don't actually know where those are. Presumably you can find *one* of them. If you rename that to "AddApplicationTemp", then go back to Program.cs, put the cursor in AddApplication and then press F12 (go to member), what happens?

Comment: @JonSkeet The error changes to 
Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddApplication' and no accessible extension method 'AddApplication' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when i rename my method, when press F12 nothing happens, i try to use visual studio search in files and i have only 1 AddApplication() method

Comment: Interesting. If you change the calling code to call `.AddApplicationTemp()` do you go back to having two errors? If so, it sounds like the code is being included twice somehow. Please post your project file (in the question) as that may have the answer.

Comment: No if i do like this i have the same error The call is ambigious

Comment: @JonSkeet I add link to code repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how your projects are organized on the file system.

You've got `BublerProject.csproj` in a directory which itself contains all your other projects. That means all the C# files are being compiled in `BublerProject` *and* in the other projects - which is what's causing the conflict.

Instead, it would be better to have a directory structure like this:

```
- BublerSolution
  |
  +- BublerSolution.sln
  |
  +- BublerProject
     |
     +- BublerProject.csproj
     +- Program.cs (etc)
  |
  +- Application
     |
     +- Application.csproj
     +- Dependency.cs
  +- ... (other projects)
```

In other words, your top level directory *just* has the solution file, and a subdirectory per project. That way you never get one project nested inside another.

Unfortunately Visual Studio can easily end up creating a project and a solution next to each other, which leads to this sort of situation. If you always start with a new *solution* and then add projects to it (instead of starting with a new *project* and saving a solution from that) then you can usually avoid this.